# Setting up schema and default values for node properties in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm using Neo4j 5 and I want to set up a schema for some node properties. Specifically, I want to set the data type for a property such as setting name as "string" and age as a "number" for the User label.

Is there any way to define a default value for properties in Neo4j?

Additionally, does Neo4j support something like SQL trigger? If so, how can I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** since Neo4j 5.9 (Enterprise Edition - which you get for free with Neo4j Desktop), type constraints are available, see https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/syntax/#constraints-syntax-create-node-exists and https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/syntax/#constraints-syntax-create-rel-prop-type.

**Original answer:**
Property Type Constraints are not supported yet by Neo4j.

The best you can have at the moment are property existence constraints, but they do not enforce a single type and are available only to the Enterprise Edition: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/

Comment: Thank you for your response! I also wanted to ask about setting default values and triggers in Neo4j. If Neo4j does not support default values, is it possible to use triggers to set default values automatically in this case?

Comment: Take a look at APOC triggers: https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/overview/apoc.trigger/

Answer (score 0):

If I want a node property to be of a specific type, I define this in the application layer, in my case C#.
I then manage any updates to this type for existing nodes using scripts.
Neo4j does not restrict adding different types to a property, this link give a reasonable synopsis https://community.neo4j.com/t/data-type-of-a-property/1309

This link explains the Neo4j Triggers https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/background-operations/triggers/